# Ionic 5 IOS cannot send data to Google Tag Manager

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, google-tag-manager, ionic-native

I've spent hard time to send data to gtm(Google Tag Manager) in ionic ios .

android and web are sending gtm very well. 
but ios dosen't working it.

My ionic version is 5.4.4. 
Cordova version is 9.0.0

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

I set them in config.xml

and install cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@4.1.2

I think something in ios prevent to request gtm. 
but I don't have idea to solve it.

already read this article  https://www.multiminds.eu/blog/2016/12/06/google-analytics-and-tag-manager-with-ionic-and-cordova-apps/

I do that,  not work for me.

please help me.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issues: web and Android work, iOS doesn't. According to the posts from here https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1100 it should be possible to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by switching from cookies storage to local storage. 
Follow the steps from this comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1433#issuecomment-644086704